# C# How can I call an interface method from my derived class

Tags: c#

I have a class that implements the interface `IPerson`. I wanna call form my class a method implemented in the interface, and I get this error: ***CS0103   The name 'SayMyName' does not exist in the current context***  How can I call a method implemented in an interface from a derived class?

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string SayMyName()
    {
        return "MyName";
    }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public void Method()
    {
        SayMyName();//ERROR CS0103 The name 'SayMyName' does not exist in the current context
    }
}
```

Comment: Interfaces don't implement anything

Comment: @Danny They can now. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/

Comment: Huh.  What will they think of next?  In *my* day we called those abstract classes.... :D

Comment: There are no derived classes in the sample code... Only an interface and a class *implementing* this interface, and the interface has a method with *default implementation*... So if duplicate is not enough check out other search results for correct terms https://www.bing.com/search?&q=c%23+call+default+method+interface%20site:stackoverflow.com and [edit] question using proper terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need explicit cast to access default implementation, provided by the interface.

```
((IPerson)this).SayMyName();
```